# Automatically reload Iframe only if source exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, iframe

What I have is an automatically generated webpage (the source of which I don't control) and I want it to refresh if a user leaves the page open. To do this I'm attempting to embed the page in a second page with a full page Iframe, the contents of which refreshes every 10 seconds.

My current code usually works, but occasionally the automatically generating webpage is being re-written at the same time the page with the Iframe tries to reload. When this happens the Iframe page crashes and the user needs to know to manually refresh the page. To fix this problem I would like to check for the existence of the generated page and only reload the Iframe if it exists **(any easier alternative ideas would be appreciated as well)**. This is all being done on a local intranet (no same-domain issues or the like).

Existing Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="AutomaticReports\Dashboard\jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script>
function resizeIframe(obj) {
obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
 obj.style.width = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollWidth + 'px';
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<iframe id="iframe" src="AutomaticReports\Dashboard\DBtrial.mhtml" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" onload="resizeIframe(this)"></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">

        function reloadIFrame() {
            $('#iframe').attr('src', $('#iframe').attr('src'));
            return false;
        };

window.setInterval(function() {
     reloadIFrame()
 }, 10000);

</script>


<script>

$.ajax({
type: 'HEAD',
url: 'AutomaticReports/Dashboard/DBtrial.mhtml',
success: function() {
    alert('Page found.');
},  
error: function() {
    alert('Page not found.');
}
});


</script>
```

Where the automatically generated file is DBtrial.html.

The bottom script block is where I am testing an ajax request to see if a local html file exists. I have tried modifying this several times, but it always alerts as 'Page not found.'

Comment: The URL path separator is `/`. The backslash is an escape character in JS.

Comment: Fixed the path in my source code with no improvement, thanks for picking that out though.